# UnlockField not working in CakePHP

Tags: javascript, forms, security, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

Just trying to make a pretty standard User-edit page.  The 'password' and 're-password' start hidden, but can be turned "on" by clicking the "Edit Password" button.

But - I keep getting the "auth" blackhole error from the Security Component.

Per [the CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3aunlockField), I tried unlocking the fields with this in the View (tried before the fields, after the fields, just inside the Form, just before the form, and at the end of the form:

```
$this->Form->unlockField('User.password');
$this->Form->unlockField('User.re-password');
```

But - doesn't help.  The only way I could get it to work was to completely unlock the entire action (does not seem ideal):

```
$this->Security->unlockedActions = array('admin_edit');
```

If I don't disable the fields, then it works, but I need to disable them because if I don't, the built-in "notEmpty" aspect causes javascript errors when looking for those fields.

**View/HTML:**

```
<div id="edit-password-area" style="display:none;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.password', array('class'=>'input-xxlarge form-control', 'value'=>'', 'disabled'=>'disabled')); ?>
        <p class="note">Must be at least 8 characters in length.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Verify Password</label>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.re_password', array('type'=>'password', 'class'=>'input-xxlarge form-control', 'value'=>'', 'disabled'=>'disabled')); ?>
        <p class="note">Must exactly match the "Password".</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="edit-password-button-area">
    <a href="javascript:showPasswordArea();">Edit Password</a>
</div>

<div id="dont-edit-password-button-area" style="display:none;">
    <a href="javascript:hidePasswordArea();">Don't Edit Password</a>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
function showPasswordArea() {
    $('#edit-password-area').show();
    $('#edit-password-area input').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#dont-edit-password-button-area').show();
    $('#edit-password-button-area').hide();
    $('#UserPassword').focus();
}
function hidePasswordArea() {
    $('#edit-password-area').hide();
    $('#edit-password-area input').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#dont-edit-password-button-area').hide();
    $('#edit-password-button-area').show();
}
</script>
```

Comment: where you able to solve this by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```
$this->Security->unlockedFields = array('yourfield');
```