# UnlockField not working in CakePHP for array

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have a form that has to handle some elements as part of an array.

```
echo $this->Form->control('config.sys_file_id', ['type' => 'number']);
echo $this->Form->control('click_enlarge', ['type' => 'checkbox']);
echo $this->Form->control('config.max_width', ['type' => 'number']);
echo $this->Form->control('config.max_height', ['type' => 'number']);
echo $this->Form->control('config.fixed_width', ['type' => 'number']);
echo $this->Form->control('config.fixed_height', ['type' => 'number']);
```

This would work fine, except I need to handle `config.sys_file_id` with some JS.

I know that I have to call `$this->Form->unlockField()`, but I can't figure out the right syntax to use when the field is part of an array.
So far I've tried

```
$this->Form->unlockField('sys_file_id');
$this->Form->unlockField('config');
$this->Form->unlockField('config.sys_file_id');
$this->Form->unlockField('config[sys_file_id]');
```

but the request still gets black-holed by the `SecurityComponent`.

I have stumbled upon these two questions [How to 'unlock' a field in a CakePHP form when it is part of a hasMany association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938555/how-to-unlock-a-field-in-a-cakephp-form-when-it-is-part-of-a-hasmany-associati) and [UnlockField not working in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347122/unlockfield-not-working-in-cakephp) but they are both very old and refer to CakePHP 2, while I'm using CakePHP 4.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for unlocking the input (when is an array) from the view is with a dot:

```
$this->Form->unlockField('config.sys_file_id');
```

https://api.cakephp.org/4.4/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#unlockField()

But make sure to use `$this->Form->unlockField()` between the `$this->Form->create()` and `$this->Form->end();`:

```
echo $this->Form->create();

echo $this->Form->control('config.sys_file_id', ['type' => 'number']);
echo $this->Form->control('click_enlarge', ['type' => 'checkbox']);
echo $this->Form->control('config.max_width', ['type' => 'number']);
echo $this->Form->control('config.max_height', ['type' => 'number']);
echo $this->Form->control('config.fixed_width', ['type' => 'number']);
echo $this->Form->control('config.fixed_height', ['type' => 'number']);

// before form end
$this->Form->unlockField('config.sys_file_id');


echo $this->Form->end();
```

If you place `$this->Form->unlockField('config.sys_file_id');` outside the form `end()` or `create()` you'll get a CakePHP exception:

> FormProtector instance has not been created. Ensure you have loaded
> the FormProtectionComponent in your controller and called
> FormHelper::create() before calling FormHelper::unlockField().

I tested this code on CakePHP 4.4 Strawbery and it works.

If your **JAVASCRIPT code is altering other fields** by mistake, your problem is there.

Comment: I tried leaving only `$this->Form->unlockField('config.sys_file_id');` and I still get the `request has been black-holed` error. And yes, `unlockField` is being called between `$this->Form->create();` and `$this->Form->end();`. I'm running CakePHP 4.3.10.

Comment: Maybe when you change this field with Javascript you also alter other fields? Can you update the answer with the javascript code used to manipulate this form/field?

Comment: You are right, I tried commenting the `config.sys_file_id` line from the form entirely and even posting the form without making any alterations to the content (by just opening the page and clicking submit immediately) and I still got the same error. Ugh, if only Cake's error was a bit more precise and there was a way to understand which field is causing the problem... :/

Comment: Your problem seems to be elsewhere... Your javascript is altering other fields I guess.

Comment: @mrodo If you have debug mode enabled, CakePHP will give you a very detailed message about what exactly is mismatching, down to the individual field. btw, you may want to consider switching to the form protection component instead, as the security component is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue ,because I placed the                     Form->unlockField('myField'); ?>  before the    $this->Form->end() line, and it was no working, but I fixed moving the unlockField method after the $this->Form->create() line. Now it works!